# why azure artifacts include all reference 3rd packages

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-artifacts

I have two packages (A & B)

1. package-B reference package-A
2. package-A reference some 3rd packages from nuget

When I publish the package-B to Azure Artifacts ,
why all 3rd packages from nuget are Also publish to the Azure Artifacts , but if I just publish package-A to the Azure Artifacts , that just have package-A

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the 'Upstream sources' setting enabled for this artifacts feed:

[image: Upstream sources enabled]

Microsoft Docs on [Upstream sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/concepts/upstream-sources?view=azure-devops) states:

> Upstream sources enable you to use a single feed to store both the packages you produce and the packages you consume from "remote feeds": both public package managers (npmjs.com, NuGet.org, Maven Central, and PyPI) and Artifacts feeds. Once you've enabled an upstream source, any user connected to your feed can install a package from the remote feed, and your feed will save a copy.

You can remove upstream sources like this:

- Go to the feed in Azure DevOps
- Click the gear-icon on the top right
- Open the right-most tab Upstream sources
- Remove any upstream sources you might have